# What is the advantage of using xampp? Why not directly install Apache, PHP, composer, MySQL and phpmyadmin?

Tags: xampp

I am a new user of Ubuntu. I am using the desktop version.

I just directly installed apache2, required php version, composer, phpmyadmin and mysql. I have configured them manually. I view directly from `www/html` folder.

So, why would a Linux user require XAMPP?

I know that I need an artificial Linux environment in a Windows OS to run PHP. So I have to install XAMPP. But why in Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a common enough situation: I'm a user without administrative rights. I could be using a lab system in university, or something like that. The administrator does not want to install LAMP (for whatever reason). Or maybe they have installed LAMP, but the configuration is not what I desire.

So I use XAMPP, configuring it so that it does not need any administrator privileges.

Comment: Hmm, So it is for users without sudo writes or those who can't config LAMP due to privileges issue. Thanks buddy.